# Dividing Table into 3 close to equal groups without breaking earlier grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a temporary table that I am calling that holds Header, Details, and Total Records in rows and the columns are a scrubbed version of the data I am working with below.

| SCODE | TYPE | DETAIL | ICOUNT | FMT | TYPEROW | FULLROW | DENSERANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CODE1 | TYPE1 | NULL | NULL | H | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| CODE1 | NULL | DETAIL | 2 | D | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| CODE1 | NULL | DETAIL | 1 | D | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| CODE1 | TYPE1 - TOTAL | NULL | 3 | T | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| CODE1 | TYPE2 | NULL | NULL | H | 1 | 5 | 2 |
| CODE1 | NULL | DETAIL | 1 | D | 2 | 6 | 2 |
| CODE1 | TYPE2 - TOTAL | NULL | 1 | T | 4 | 7 | 2 |
| CODE1 | TYPE3 | NULL | NULL | H | 1 | 8 | 3 |
| CODE1 | NULL | DETAIL | 2 | D | 2 | 9 | 3 |
| CODE1 | NULL | DETAIL | 1 | D | 3 | 10 | 3 |
| CODE1 | TYPE3 - TOTAL | NULL | 3 | T | 4 | 11 | 3 |
| CODE1 | TYPE4 | NULL | NULL | H | 1 | 12 | 4 |
| CODE1 | NULL | DETAIL | 2 | D | 2 | 13 | 4 |
| CODE1 | NULL | DETAIL | 1 | D | 3 | 14 | 4 |
| CODE1 | NULL | DETAIL | 1 | D | 4 | 15 | 4 |
| CODE1 | NULL | DETAIL | 3 | D | 5 | 16 | 4 |
| CODE1 | NULL | DETAIL | 1 | D | 6 | 17 | 4 |
| CODE1 | TYPE4 - TOTAL | NULL | 7 | T | 7 | 18 | 4 |

Essentially this is a list of totals and details with headers.  There are upwards of 30 different Types that will have a Total record and Header record. Detail records can vary between 1 and more than 100 values.

The goal is to turn this single table above into three separate temp tables that all have as equal number of rows as possible without interrupting the DENSERANK groups.  IE all DENSERANK of 1 are in the same column. If needed I can provide a larger data set to work with as well.

Table name is #temptwo.  I have attempted an NTILE to get group sizes but have not had luck with getting this to work when groups have more uneven numbers and am running low on ideas to try.

```sql
Declare @Number_Of_Groups tinyint = 3;

WITH cte_staging
AS
(
    SELECT * 
        , NTILE(@Number_Of_Groups) OVER(ORDER BY prow ASC) AS GroupID
    FROM #temptwo
)
 
SELECT GroupID
    , COUNT(1) AS TotalRows
    into #group
FROM cte_staging
GROUP BY GroupID
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Comment: SQL Server (2016) <> MySQL. What are you *really* using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server(2016) and am working out of SSMS

Comment: Pet peeve: [The semicolon (`;`) is a statement terminator](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-the-semicolon-is-a-statement-terminator/) *not* a "beginningator". It goes at the *end* of **all** your statements, not at the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated. Not terminating your statements properly is deprecated, so you should really try to get into the habit of properly terminating your statements now, so that your code doesn't break if the change is ever forced through.

Comment: I will make sure to edit this in my future codes.  Do you know how I can divide this into 3 separate tables of rough equivalence without interrupting the denserank?

Answer (score 0):

Think about how you would do this by hand.  First you would count the records and divide by 3.  That would be your target.

Then you would add the WHOLE group to our output if adding that group would be less than the target plus an acceptable amount to go over (say 15% -- this depends on the size of your groups vs the size of the split.)

Repeat for each output group.

Now lets think about this for SQL.  In SQL you work in sets not records -- so you have to modify the above process for set based approach.  As an output I would expect a table that has

```
OUTPUT_GROUP_NUMBER     DENSE_RANK
```

This table would have multiple rows for each DENSE_RANKs in an output group.

You also need to know the counts for each DENSE_RANK, which you can get like this:

```
 SELECT  DENSERANK, COUNT(*) AS CNT
 FROM #temptwo
 GROUP BY DENSERANK
```

And of course the total rows and our goal size (here is where you could change 3 to something else or use a parameter)

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT, 
        CAST(COUNT(*)/3 AS INT) AS GROUP_SIZE,
        CAST(((COUNT(*)/3) * 1.15) AS INT) AS GOAL
 FROM #temptwo
```

Next we need to select items that are less than our target + 15%  To do this we use a recursive CTE

```
 WITH RCOUNT AS (
   SELECT  DENSERANK, COUNT(*) AS CNT
   FROM #temptwo
   GROUP BY DENSERANK
 ), TCOUNT AS (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT, 
          3 AS GROUPMAX,
          CAST(COUNT(*)/3 AS INT) AS GROUP_SIZE,
          CAST(((COUNT(*)/3) * 1.15) AS INT) AS GOAL
   FROM #temptwo
 ), GROUP_RANK AS (
    SELECT 1 AS OUTPUT_GROUP_NUMBER, 1 AS DENSE_RANK, CNT AS T_CNT
    FROM RCOUNT
    WHERE DENSERANK = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      CASE WHEN (GROUP_RANK.T_CNT+RCOUNT.CNT <= TCOUNT.GOAL) OR 
                (GROUP_RANK.OUTPUT_GROUP_NUMBER = TCOUNT.GROUPMAX)
           THEN GROUP_RANK.OUTPUT_GROUP_NUMBER -- It fits
           ELSE GROUP_RANK.OUTPUT_GROUP_NUMBER+1 -- Does not fit, put in next one
       END AS OUTPUT_GROUP_NUMBER,
       CAST(RCOUNT.DENSERANK AS INT) AS DENSE_RANK,
       CASE WHEN (GROUP_RANK.T_CNT+RCOUNT.CNT <= TCOUNT.GOAL) OR 
                 (GROUP_RANK.OUTPUT_GROUP_NUMBER = TCOUNT.GROUPMAX)
            THEN GROUP_RANK.T_CNT + RCOUNT.CNT -- It fits
            ELSE RCOUNT.CNT -- Does not fit, put in next one
       END AS T_CNT
    FROM GROUP_RANK
    JOIN RCOUNT ON RCOUNT.DENSERANK = GROUP_RANK.DENSE_RANK + 1
    CROSS JOIN TCOUNT  -- This is a single row
 )
 SELECT OUTPUT_GROUP_NUMBER, DENSE_RANK
 FROM GROUP_RANK
```

Comment: Thank you that is incredibly helpful and looks so close to what I am looking for but I ran this for some data that has more ends up with a DENSERANK from 1 to 8 and CNT of all 3 with one 4  for the first query and the second query came up with 25 CNT 8 GROUP_SIZE and 9 GOAL.   I ended up with some results returning a 4 for OUTPUT_GROUP_NUMBER .  It looks related to the GOAL as when I move the 1.15 to 1.5 it works with some data but not other sets. Is there a way I can have it figure out what the best Target + % would be to fit inside a set number of columns?

Comment: @jbai555 -- Thanks for the edits -- PLEASE TURN OFF TABS IN YOUR EDITOR -- you put tabs all over my code and made it really hard to edit.

Comment: @jbai555 -- 1.5 seems to high for me.  That is why I picked what I did -- I wouldn't every go above 1.25   Probably the best way is start at 1.0 and then if the last group is to big then increase the size of the "overflow" till there is a good result.

Comment: for the example you gave if you change the < TCOUNT.GOAL to <= TCOUNT.GOAL then it will work (as 9 will hold 3 groups of 3 just fine.)

Comment: I think I removed the tabs but I may be wrong sorry I am new to stackoverflows setup.  I added in those conditions but found that when one column is very large it keeps wanting to put items into a 4th column or group.  It appears to happen when a large group is towards the bottom of the list but I do need these to stay in order by type.  Would there be a way to add in an evaluation for if the next column is going to be increasing larger than the first sets to prevent the 4th from being there? Potentially using the OUTPUT_GROUP_NUMBER as a factor?

Comment: @jbai555 -- see fix in the  code... added in "group max" parameter